# Manually manage and update Intel TBB flow graph?

Tags: c++, tbb, tbb-flow-graph

I have successfully prototyped an application using Intel's awesome TBB flow graph library. It seems to work quite well, but now I need to refactor the code into a production-ready version.

Previously, I have worked with some larger and more "over-developed" frameworks for this particular domain (the work is in image processing and previous applications have used ITK/VTK). For this application, however, I am trying to take a lower-level and more focused approach.

Currently, I am just assembling my entire graph in `main()` which is obviously not sustainable. I'd like to allow the pipeline to run iteratively so that I can grab output data from each stage and display it for debug/analysis purposes.

My idea so far is to abstract each logical "stage" of the application into a class that accepts a `&tbb::flow::graph` as a constructor argument and internally stores a reference to the graph node it controls. I can have the wrapper class allocate an additional `tbb::flow::broadcast_node` at the output and an async node after that to fire off events.

Is this a sensible design concept? Generally speaking, how have others integrated the TBB flow graph concepts into the structure of their application? The examples and documentation are quite scant for this particular portion of the TBB library.

Answer (score 1):

As with any design, I don't think there is a clearly right or wrong way to do it. I don't know your code good enough, but breaking the code up by logical stages is probably a good idea.

When it comes to frameworks like TBB, a design decision that you have to make is whether you should hide all framework aspects behind an interface. The advantage is that you could later swap out the implementation with another implementation (e.g., replace TBB by OpenMP). On the other hand, introducing an additional layer might not be needed in all cases. Especially, if it is unlikely that you will ever replaced TBB.

The design design that you describe in your question is how to structure the framework dependent part. It depends very much on the concrete algorithm that you are implementing. For instance, if it consists of applying separate transformations on one images, creating one class per transformation step could be a good approach.

In addition, it might make sense to wrap everything in a function or class. If the operation that you are implementing takes one image as an input and produces one image as an output, this is something that can be hidden behind an interface that hides the implementation details (in this case TBB).